# Weird decimal output

Tags: java, decimal

Okay, I figured this program would be really easy. However, when the console displays the x values (shown in the system.out.), I'm getting "When x is 1.20000000000002....". 
I know that 1.1 + 0.1 is not 1.200000000002, so I'm just wondering if there's a fault in my syntax or something. If you decide to run the code to see, you'll instantly see my issue. 
If anyone has any suggestions, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Thank You

```
public class EulersMethod {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double x = 1;
        double y = 1;
        double h = 0.1;

        while(x <= 1.4){
            System.out.println("When x is " + x + ", y is " + y);

            y = y + h * (- x - y);
            x = x + h;

        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Read about how floating point is done in computers.

Comment: [This](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) may interest you. Also answer for most precision problems is `BigDecimal` class.

Comment: Sitck with powers of 2, like 0.5, 0.25 etc. And don't run out of bits.

Comment: @doctorlove That comment is cool! :) Says it all!

Comment: `I know that 1.1 + 0.1 is not 1.200000000002` You know it wrong. _[swipes hand in front of face]_ **These are not the decimals you're looking for!**

Comment: I'd rather not read up on it. This isn't for a computer science class. I'd just like to know what is going on with the syntax

Comment: It's not the syntax - its the semantics.

Comment: @BradleyHall This has 0 to do with syntax, and all to do with computer science.

Comment: "I'd rather not read up on it"?? You're going to encounter this problem a lot more if you don't.

Comment: Alright. I could reiterate myself, but I've got better things to do than argue with trolls. Thanks to John Smith for answering my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`0.1` can not be precisely represented by a `double` type, so there must be some approximation/compromise to make. And for a `double` it is usually has only about 16 to 17 digit of significant digits. That is why you could not get `1.2` exactly.

Comment: Thank you. Seems to be short and simple

Answer (score 1):

To expand on my comment, some numbers can be written precisely in doubles, like 1/2, while others cannot.

```
0.5 = 1/2
```

so can be written exactly as a sum of powers of two

```
0.1 = 1/10 = 1/16 + a bit = 1/16 + 1/32 + a bit more... etc
```

The bit more can never be exactly a power of two, so you get the closest it can manage. It may overshoot, or undershoot.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good article on why floats are not exact (or why they should never be used in financial calculations): http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-are-floating-point-calculations-so-inaccurate.htm

What you really want is BigDecimal.

Here's a short tutorial from JavaWorld: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-06-2001/jw-0601-cents.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `DecimalFormat` to clean it up if you like.

```
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("0.0");
String decimalValueAsString = format.format(yourDecimalValue);
```

[Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

You could also use Decimal formatting with [RoundingMode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html) and the method [setRoundingMode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#setRoundingMode%28java.math.RoundingMode%29)